# Appending argv entries to an array (dynamically populating an array) in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, dynamic

I'm trying to append content from the argument list (`"$@"`), excluding `$1` and also any value starting with a dash, to an array in bash.

My current code follows, but doesn't operate correctly:

```
BuildTypeList=("armv7" "armv6")
BuildTypeLen=${#BuildTypeList[*]}

while [ "$2" != "-*" -a "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    BuildTypeList["$BuildTypeLen"] = "$2"
    BuildTypeLen=${#BuildTypeList[*]}
    shift
done
```

My intent is to add content to `BuildTypeList` at runtime, rather than defining its content statically as part of the source.

Comment: The most immediate reason the original code didn't work, by the way, is the spaces around the `=` sign in the assignment. `foo=bar` is an assignment in shell; `foo = bar` is not.

Comment: (Also, `[ foo != bar ]` is not a glob expression; the bash extension `[[ ]]` is needed for that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler to just iterate over all the arguments, and selectively append them to your list.

```
BuildTypeList=("armv7" "armv6")
first_arg=$1
shift;

for arg in "$@"; do
    [[ $arg != -* ]] && BuildTypeList+=( "$arg" )
done

# If you really need to make sure all the elements
# are shifted out of $@
shift $#
```

Comment: make sure you quote `"$arg"` when you append it to the array.

Answer (score 13):

Append to an array with the `+=` operator:

```
ary=( 1 2 3 )
for i in {10..15}; do
    ary+=($i)
done
echo "${ary[@]}" # => 1 2 3 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a plenty of manuals on this subject. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html, for example. Or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays, or http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays.

Comment: Bash has supported simple arrays for a very long time; bash 2.0, released in the mid 90s, supported them. I hope no one is using a version that doesn't.

Comment: Please don't suggest the ABS as a documentation source -- it's out-of-date and often has advice that's flat wrong. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is more actively supported and maintained.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy might be, I just picked the top link from Google, mostly because pointing to lmgtfy is not too constructive. The point is that there're numerous resources on the subject.